# C# Datagridview How to set value for DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have populated my datagridview which has one combobox column.

this way i have populated my combobox column of datagridview.

```
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = "0";
                dr[1] = "--Select--";
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

                (dgListLineitems.Columns["colBM"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = dt;
                (dgListLineitems.Columns["colBM"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember = "BM_Element";
                (dgListLineitems.Columns["colBM"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember = "Code";

            }
```

This way i set value for combobox column for each row but no luck

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgListLineitems.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //dgListLineitems.Rows[i].Cells["colBM"].Value = "0";
                dgListLineitems.Rows[i].Cells["colBM"].Value = "--Select--";
            }
```

i use this `dgListLineitems.Rows[i].Cells["colBM"].Value = "0";` but no item is selected in combobox column.

i want to show each combobox in datagridview should have this default text  **--Select--**

where i made the mistake. please guide me. Thanks

### Full code sample for grid bind with combobox column

```
//Grid bind
dgListLineitems.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgListLineitems.DataSource = ListOfElements.Copy();

dgListLineitems.Columns["colRow"].DataPropertyName = "RowNumber";
dgListLineitems.Columns["colLineitem"].DataPropertyName = "LineItem";

dgListLineitems.Columns[0].Width = 60;
dgListLineitems.Columns[1].Width = 75;
dgListLineitems.Columns[2].Width = 498;
dgListLineitems.Columns[3].Width = 502;

//Bind combobox column
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "0";
    dr[1] = "--Select--";
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

    (dgListLineitems.Columns["colBM"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = dt;
    (dgListLineitems.Columns["colBM"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember = "BM_Element";
    (dgListLineitems.Columns["colBM"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember = "Code";
}

//Set value for combobox column
for (int i = 0; i < dgListLineitems.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dgListLineitems.Rows[i].Cells["colBM"].Value = "0";
}
```

Comment: From your current code, the line … `dgListLineitems.Rows[i].Cells["colBM"].Value = "0";` … should work and display the “--Select--” text in the combo box. In addition, it is unknown if the combo box column is BOUND to a column in the GRIDS `DataSource` or is the column “detached” from the grids data source? Using the combo box column's `ValueMamber` sort of “implies” that the combo box column IS bound to a column in the grids data source. Otherwise, setting the columns `ValueMember` property is somewhat superfluous.

Comment: unfortunately this code `dgListLineitems.Rows[i].Cells["colBM"].Value = "0";` not setting default value. i bind my grid and also i bind combobox column of grid separately.

Comment: In my test the code works. You will need to show the context by which your posted code is called from. If you are not getting errors, and it “appears” the combo box column is added to the grid… if you select a combo box, do you see all the values it should have… “including” the added “0” –Select--“… ? …

Comment: Also, it is still not clear to me if the GRIDS data source has a column in it that should be BOUND to the combo box column you added in your code. I do not see the combo box columns `DataPropertyName` set. So… the combo box column would be “detached” from the grid’s data source and you could drop the `ValueMember` and just use the `DisplayMember.`

Comment: @JohnG please have a look at my Full code sample and advise me what is wrong there. also suggest what to change in code. thanks

Comment: Well… I do not know what to tell you… the last snippet of code I copy/paste into a button click and it sets the combo box values as you want. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Since it “appears” that there are at least 4 columns that are created in the designer including the combo box column, AND it also “appears” that of those four columns, ONLY TWO (2) of those four columns are bound to the grids data source (RowNumber and LineItem) … and the combo box is NOT BOUND to the grids data source, then… drop setting the combo columns `ValueMember` and just use the `DisplayMember` and set the value of the cell to “—Select—“. If you set the `ValueMember` property, then THOSE values are stored in the grids cell even though it displays something else.